# Combine different levels of multiple regression analysis?

Tags: multiple-regression

I am trying to make a model in Python to predict the influence of different parameters on the total amount of leakage trough an orifice. I tested the following parameters:

- Pressure level (6 levels)
- Orifice size (3 levels)
- Orifice shape (categorical variable, round or not round)
- Fluid viscosity (categorical, water or blood/milk)

The data looks like this:
[image: Data exit flow]

I thought this would be a classic case of a multiple linear regression analysis, but I have a problem. When I look at the pairplot, I see a some relations (strong between orifice size and exit flow, as expected). See following pairplots:

[image: Pairplot with hue=fluid viscosity]

[image: Pairplot with hue=orifice shape]

When I work this out, the orifice size and shape have a high regression coefficient, and the fluid viscosity and pressure have a low regression coefficient.

[image: Enter the image description here]

However, when I look at the relation between the pressure vs exit flow per diameter orifice size, I also see a strong relation for each size independently.

[image: pressure vs exit flow per diameter orifice size]

So I know there is a relation between the pressure and the exit flow, but in the total regression, they middle out to be 0 (or low).

So how to handle this problem? I thought of the following options:

1. Create three different multiple regression models, each for 1 orifice size. Combine the models afterwards. Is this possible? The independent variables are the same.
2. Split the data in the pressure for orifice size 1, pressure orifice size 2 and pressure orifice size 3 and get more coefficients in the final mulitple regression model. So 3 for pressure, 1 for orifice size, 1 for orifice shape and 1 for fluid viscosity.
3. Create two multiple regression models. One for the variables orifice size, orifice shape and fluid viscosity together. And the other for pressure per orifice size. Combine the models afterwards.

I don't know if it is correct to combine the models afterwards, but since the variables are the same, I thought it might be. Or is there a different solution?

Comment: It could help posting the data for people to have a look. From the figure above, I would expect the model `flow ~ pressure + size` to have all terms positively and convincingly associated with flow. However, including additional variables could make the effect of `pressure` indistinguishable from zero due to some collinearity.

Comment: @dariober : thanks! I added a picture from the data. After this post, I scaled the data, which seemed to change the influence of the pressure level. Before scaling, the coefficient was 10 and now it is 130, which is almost the same as for the influence of shape.